# How to watch live objects at run time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-management, visual-studio-2012

Is there some way to watch all my in memory `(non-disposed)` objects ?

this can help in complex dirty old apps to keep track of memory and find the leak reasons faster

thank you.

Comment: I recommend [Redgate ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) - there's a 14 day free trial version so you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a profiler to track object allocation/de-allocation over the run of an application. Take a look at the [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) or a commercial one like [Red Gate ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler) or [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) is another useful tool specifically for this purpose.